# Custom Keyboards Control Cursor

Tags: ios, swift, ios-app-extension, custom-keyboard

Today I took a challenge to create a custom iOS keyboard that reverses the input string and displays it on the textview.

**Input**:
`Hello StackOverflow!`

**Output**:
`!wolfrevOkcats olleH`

I have tried storing the button titles into a `[NSString]` array and displaying it out on the textview using `reverse()` function. 

**Here is my code**:

```
  @IBAction func keyboardBtnPressed(sender: AnyObject) {

    let button = sender as! UIButton
    //identify the button title
    let buttonTitle = button.titleForState(.Normal)

    //letters and string are [NSString]() arrays.

    if let currentTitle = buttonTitle{
    switch currentTitle {
    case "Space":
    //if user pressed space bar, then display the result on the screen
        for letter in self.letters {
            (textDocumentProxy as! UIKeyInput).insertText(letter as String)
            letters.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)
            self.string.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)
        }
        (textDocumentProxy as! UIKeyInput).insertText(" ")
    default:
       //else append the letters to the array
        string.append(currentTitle)
        self.letters = self.string.reverse()

        }
    }

}
```

The output:
`elloH !wolfrevOkcats` 
 Which is not identical to: `!wolfrevOkcats olleH` 
 

Is it possible for a custom keyboard to control the cursor, so instead of moving from `left to right` it goes from `right to left`?

After doing some research I found I can edit the `Info.plist` file and change the bool value in `PrefersRightToLeft` dictionary.

 This is **NOT** allowed.

Is there any better way?
Thanks.

Comment: `_textField.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(-1.0, 1.0);` it actually mirrors the letters as well, but it is a very lighthearted and quick solution – maybe it can match your expectations.